# NumberFormatException fail to parse a string

Tags: android, parsing, int

```
String daniel;    
daniel = hi.getWebPage("http://daniandroid.honor.es/");
```

What the getWebPage returns is a String type with the content found there. 
This worked 2 days ago.

On this URL - >

```
    <?php
echo"300"
?>
```

When I try to convert the "content" from string to "int" I get error and the app crashes.

```
int verif = Integer.parseInt(daniel);
```

What I get as error is

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "300"
```

I did the same code 2 days ago and it worked.

EDIT:
I tried

```
String daniel;
daniel = "test";
```

What I get is

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "test"
```

Comment: daniel = "test" won't ever work because you are trying to convert it to a number, but its weird its failing with "300"

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild then re-run the app?

Comment: it is strange that String is even throwing that exception. Will it be possible to try and provide the complete code?

Comment: https://mycodestock.com/public/snippet/14354   line 69

Comment: All the project is on about 4-5 files, it too complex to post all things.

Comment: It's so weird because this link I provided you is not posted now.   I posted it some hours ago because it worked and I wanted to have a backup. Looks like now is not working. I replaced all the code with this one, still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try `daniel.trim()` maybe some whitespace come from univerce ;)

Comment: Don't work. As I mention, I tried daniel = "test";  the same error.

Comment: Ok but this test dont have a sense. Because everybody know that "test" is not a int. Better test is daniel = "300"

Comment: You're right.For a moment I tought it will convert as characters are converted in C++   char d = 'd';  int r = (int)d;